# Visual Basic datagrid change row color when a product expired

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid which is connected to ms access. I have a column named "Expiration date". I am making the row of the datagrid becomes red when a product has expired. I am having trouble with this code.

```
 Private Sub BoticaDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles BoticaDataGridView.DataBindingComplete
    For i = 0 To BoticaDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim expDate As Date = BoticaDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
        Dim now = Date.Now
        If expDate > now Then
            BoticaDataGridView.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        Else
            BoticaDataGridView.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It says that "Conversion from type 'Integer' to type 'Date' is not valid." Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure  5th column has date value?

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes. In access I declared the data type of column 5 (Expiration Date) as date/time

Comment: have only this statement and see what you get in result
`Dim result = BoticaDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value`

Comment: Thank you! Finally it works. :D

Answer (score -1):

The value

```
BoticaDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
```

is not a date value for at least one row and cell 5 in your loop.

Comment: Not possible in vb6